# `with-redefs` not binding certain functions (Clojure)

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

I'm trying to test a "tic tac toe" command line game in Clojure, and want to redefine functions that use `read-line` to mock user input. However, `with-redefs` is not working as I expect, and also (seemingly) differently from other tests.

#### Here is my test

```
(ns game.setup-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [clojure.string :as st]
            [game.helpers :as gh]
            [game.setup :refer :all]))


(deftest initial-setup-test
  (testing "Can set initial options"
    (with-redefs [get-game-type-input (fn [] "1")
                  get-marker-input (fn [] "X") 
                  get-starter-input (fn [] "1")]
      (do (initial-setup my-game)
       (is (= :human (get-in @my-game [:player1 :type])))
       (is (= :human (get-in @my-game [:player2 :type])))
       (is (= [:player1 :player2] (get @my-game :up-next)))
       (is (= "X" (get-in @my-game [:player1 :marker])))
       (is (= "O" (get-in @my-game [:player2 :marker])))))))
```

#### Here are my function definitions in `setup.clj`

```
(ns game.setup)

(defn get-input [requestor validator]
  (fn [] (do (requestor)
             (if-let [input (validator (read-line))]
                      input
                      (recur)))))

(def get-marker-input (get-input request-p1-marker valid-marker?))
(def get-game-type-input (get-input request-game-type valid-type?))
(def get-starter-input (get-input request-starter-type valid-starter?))


(def set-starter
  (partial set-game-option
           get-starter-input
           starter-opts
           swap-merge
           print-starter-player))

(defn initial-setup [game-state]
  (do (set-game-type game-state)
      (set-player-markers game-state)
      (set-starter game-state)))

(defn set-game-option [input-getter attr-opts updater printer game]
  (-> (input-getter)      ; gets user input
      attr-opts           ; returns corresponding update-map
      (#(updater game %)) ; updates the game-state with update-map
      printer))           ; prints the updated game-state
```

When running this test. I still see the STDOUT output from the `request-*` function, and the test waits for input to STDIN.
So, I assume that `with-redefs` is not "re-defing" the `get-*` functions as I expect.

#### A different test that works as I expect

```
(deftest get-marker-input-test
  (testing "Reads perfect input"
    (with-redefs [read-line (fn [] "X")]
      (is (= "X" (get-marker-input))))))
```

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: I think there may be something else going wrong. Your `with-redefs` looks fine and I'm unable to reproduce this. Maybe post the rest of your code (`initial-setup` etc.), or make a minimal repro case. Also try restarting your REPL if you've been iterating on this code for a while.

Comment: Just tried restarting. No impact.

Comment: I might try reverting to Java 8 from 9... There are some other issues with 9. I'll let you know if it fixes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you aren't seeing your redef take effect is that the function under test `set-starter` via `initial-setup` uses `partial`. `partial` returns a new function that retains the reference to the previously defined function.

A simpler example:

```
boot.user=> (def my-dumb-fn (partial str "prefix"))
#'boot.user/my-dumb-fn
boot.user=> (with-redefs [str (fn [s] "hello")] (str 23))
"hello"
boot.user=> (with-redefs [str (fn [s] "hello")] (my-dumb-fn 23))
"prefix23"
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you! Do you have any suggestions for writing the test a different way, so that I can still test the functionality of the `initial-setup` function?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use not `read-line` but just `read`: it reads the input string into data structures rather than strings. More over, when it finds a space (or the end of reading form, saying more precisely), it stops reading the input preventing the rest of it of being consumed.

A special built-in macro `with-in-str` allows you to specify some certain input for testing purposes as follows:

```
(with-in-str "X 0 X 0 0 X"
  (let [turn1 (read)
        turn2 (read)
        ;; more reads ...
        ]
    [turn1
     turn2
     ;; more read values
     ]))
```

Returns

```
[X 0]
```

In other words, there is no need to redefine functions.

Comment: Great to know! Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

As @dpassen says, don't use `partial` (I never do).  Here is an alternative:

```
> lein new tupelo-app fred     ; make a new project `fred` with nice defaults
> cd fred
```

Cut & paste so looks like this:

```
~/expr/fred > cat src/tst/fred/core.clj
(ns tst.fred.core
  (:use fred.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require 
    [clojure.java.io :as io]
    [tupelo.string :as ts] )
  (:import [fred Calc]))

(def x 5)
(def  p1     (partial + x))
(defn p2 [y] (+ x y))

(dotest
  (spyx (p1 2))
  (spyx (p2 2))
  (with-redefs [x 10]
    (spyx (p1 3))
    (spyx (p2 3))))
```

and we get results:

```
---------------------------------
   Clojure 1.9.0    Java 9.0.1
---------------------------------
Testing fred.core

Testing tst.fred.core
(p1 2) => 7
(p2 2) => 7

(p1 3) => 8
(p2 3) => 13
```

So, by defining `p2` as a function (instead of a "constant" `var` with `partial`), we get the expected result and `with-redefs` works correctly.